# Duplicity + Amazon S3 Glacier. How Much "Unfreezing" to Resume Backup

Tags: backup, aws, duplicity, amazon-s3

It's been a couple of months since I last did a Duplicity backup [to Amazon S3] and, in the meantime thanks to an automatic 30-day rule I have on my Amazon buckets,  my S3 backup has been moved from the 'normal' Reduced Redundancy storage to Amazon Glacier.

Now, when I run `duply <backupname> verify -v9` I see the output getting hung up at the end with the following [This is after leaving it running overnight, as each restore from Glacier takes several hours]:

```
-------------------------
Chain start time: Sun Dec  1 14:49:39 2013
Chain end time: Fri May  1 20:18:38 2015
Number of contained backup sets: 16
Total number of contained volumes: 1438
 Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
                Full         Sun Dec  1 14:49:39 2013               318
         Incremental         Wed Dec 11 13:21:16 2013                 1
         Incremental         Wed Dec 18 19:48:07 2013                15
         Incremental         Tue Dec 31 18:45:25 2013                 4
         Incremental         Sat Jan  4 18:06:42 2014                 9
         Incremental         Sat Feb 15 15:14:59 2014                15
         Incremental         Sat Feb 15 15:43:26 2014                 1
         Incremental         Mon Feb 17 10:18:31 2014                 3
         Incremental         Mon Feb 17 10:24:57 2014                 1
         Incremental         Wed Feb 19 14:35:22 2014                 1
         Incremental         Wed Feb 19 14:38:52 2014                 1
         Incremental         Sun Mar  2 22:37:32 2014               514
         Incremental         Wed Jul  9 20:12:22 2014                26
         Incremental         Sat Dec  6 22:57:27 2014               262
         Incremental         Fri May  1 18:37:57 2015               266
         Incremental         Fri May  1 20:18:38 2015                 1
-------------------------
No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.
Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-Q5My3G-tempdir
Registering (mktemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-Q5My3G-tempdir/mktemp-DGtqcn-1
File duplicity-full.20131201T144939Z.vol1.difftar.gpg is in Glacier storage, restoring to S3
Waiting for file duplicity-full.20131201T144939Z.vol1.difftar.gpg to restore from Glacier
File duplicity-full.20131201T144939Z.vol1.difftar.gpg was successfully restored from Glacier
Registering (mktemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-Q5My3G-tempdir/mktemp-AQObTq-2
Waiting for file duplicity-inc.20131201T144939Z.to.20131211T132116Z.vol1.difftar.gpg to restore from Glacier
File duplicity-inc.20131201T144939Z.to.20131211T132116Z.vol1.difftar.gpg was successfully restored from Glacier
Registering (mktemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-Q5My3G-tempdir/mktemp-U6R9NX-3
File duplicity-inc.20131211T132116Z.to.20131218T194807Z.vol1.difftar.gpg is in Glacier storage, restoring to S3
Waiting for file duplicity-inc.20131211T132116Z.to.20131218T194807Z.vol1.difftar.gpg to restore from Glacier
File duplicity-inc.20131211T132116Z.to.20131218T194807Z.vol1.difftar.gpg was successfully restored from Glacier
Registering (mktemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-Q5My3G-tempdir/mktemp-6ZNOgl-4
File duplicity-inc.20131218T194807Z.to.20131231T184525Z.vol1.difftar.gpg is in Glacier storage, restoring to S3
Waiting for file duplicity-inc.20131218T194807Z.to.20131231T184525Z.vol1.difftar.gpg to restore from Glacier
```

Now, I was kind of expecting the latest difftar file to have to be unfrozen from Glacier, in order for Duplicity to carry on from where it left off last time. But, given backups are incremental, I'm puzzled as to why it seems to be 'unfreezing' further [earlier] difftar files. I've cancelled the command for the moment but I need to find out whether it's safe to try again. If Duplicity needs to  unfreeze a handful of difftar files, before resuming, that's fine. But with over 80GB backed up, I can't afford to let it unfreeze my entire backup archive.

Anybody got any ideas on this?

Last time, Duplicity was on my radar, I know there was talk of adding support for Glacier and the `Waiting ... to restore from Glacier` message suggest this has been done. However, as my backup files have been moved to Glacier by an automatic bucket rule, rather than explicitly through Duplicity itself, I'm not sure whether or not this has messed things up, as regards being able to resume that backup.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect you could run an `incremental` update without running `verify` first. The man page says

> Duplicity does not require access to archive files except when restoring from backup.

but based on my testing `verify` (at least) counts as a kind of restoring.